# Uploading a small .txt file and reading its line in Java Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a small txt file with few lines and read it in my rest application. I am able to get it work on my local machine with GAE (1.9.25) run time on Jetty server. However when i deploy it to cloud  and try to upload a file it throws me a runtime exception as below.

**Please note i have not enabled billing or blob store. and exception does not sate anything on these lines. So i am guessing it could not be related to it. 
As i am not saving the file and only used to read it and no write operation .. does this feature supported by app engine ?**

```
    Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.<init>()
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:206)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:179)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:457)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is my HTML, Rest Controller and Web.xml

HTML

```
<form action="rest/locality/upload" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8">
    <p>
        Select a new file : <input type="file" name="file" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Rest Controller

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fis) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))) {
        String strLine = null;
```

and Web.xml

```
<servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.smart.win.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Hope i have provided enough information

Comment: Downvoter.. Care to comment ?  why a down vote for the question.? i can provide any information if required..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my question.

Resolved it using apache commons library.

http://www.webring.org/l/rd?ring=theshogiwebring;id=13;url=http%3A%2F%2Fshogi-software%2Eblogspot%2Ein%2F2009%2F04%2Fgoogle-app-engine-and-file-upload%2Ehtml